# Geocoder does not return the location properly

Tags: google-maps-api-3, jquery-plugins

I have two arrays containing latitude and longtitude of 7 locations,and I use the following
code for getting the location of these 7 points:

```
var geocoder;
initialize();
codeLatLng();
function initialize() {

geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
```

}

```
 function codeLatLng() {
var arrlat=[45.95268273, 47.00196833,45.99168238, 46.2186456, 45.91612197, 45.91606814,     45.91606814];
var arrlon=[-66.68426012, -65.56480221, -63.98068545, -64.44419501, -66.74801471,      -66.74810832, -66.74810832];
  var input = document.getElementById("latlng").getAttribute('value');
 console.log(input);
var latlngStr = input.split(",", 2);
   var lat = parseFloat(latlngStr[0]);
   var lng = parseFloat(latlngStr[1]);
   for(var i=0;i<arrlat.length;i++)
  {    
        var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(arrlat[i], arrlon[i]);
        geocoder.geocode({
            'latLng': latlng
        }, function(results, status) {

            //document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = '' +      (results[4].formatted_address); + ''
            alert(results[4].formatted_address);
        });
  }
```

}

whenever I feed the arrays with 5 of less elements the code works properly but for more than 5 I get 5 alert showing the location of the first 5 elements but for the last 2 I get  the following error:

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '4' of null

And here is the Jfiddle link:

[link](http://jsfiddle.net/hminaee/LSDH7/)

Can anyone help?

Comment: You aren't checking the status returned by the geocoder.  You are getting a status response of OVER_QUERY_LIMIT  [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LSDH7/1/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code more defensively. Check the status of the response before using it.  If it isn't "OK", there won't be any results to process.

```
function codeLatLng() {
    var arrlat=[45.95268273, 47.00196833,45.99168238, 46.2186456, 45.91612197, 45.91606814, 45.91606814];
    var arrlon=[-66.68426012, -65.56480221, -63.98068545, -64.44419501, -66.74801471, -66.74810832, -66.74810832];
 var input = document.getElementById("latlng").getAttribute('value');
console.log(input);
    var latlngStr = input.split(",", 2);
    var lat = parseFloat(latlngStr[0]);
    var lng = parseFloat(latlngStr[1]);
    for(var i=0;i<arrlat.length;i++)
    {    
            var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(arrlat[i], arrlon[i]);
            geocoder.geocode({
                'latLng': latlng
            }, function(results, status) {
                if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK ) {
                //document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = '' + (results[4].formatted_address); + ''
                if (results.length >= 5)
                  alert(results[4].formatted_address);
                else alert("less than 5 results");
            } else alert("reverse geocode failed, status="+status);
            });
    }

}
```

See the [documentation on Status Codes](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geocoding#GeocodingStatusCodes) for what the failure codes mean.

Comment: Thanks a lot,I have a question,in the array there are 7 points but I get 6 locations and I get 1 alert says: Over query limit. What does it mean?I checked all the points and it seems all of them are correct.Do you have any idea?

Comment: from [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geocoding#GeocodingStatusCodes): `google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OVER_QUERY_LIMIT indicates that you are over your quota. Refer to the Usage limits exceeded article in the Maps for Business documentation, which also applies to non-Business users, for more information.`  Most likely you are exceeding the rate limit, for _geocoding_ that seems to allow ~10 calls, seems to be a smaller number for reverse geocoding.